# Different thing is shown in html

Tags: python, html, django

I wanna show most newest value of test_date User model.
I wrote in views.py

```
@login_required
def test(request):
    test_score = User.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('test_date')[0]
    return render(request, 'test.html',{'test_score': test_score})
```

in models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", verbose_name="imageforegin")
    test_date = models.IntegerField(max_length=100,null=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length=100,null=True)
```

in test.html

```
<h3>Your score is
      <h2 class="one"> {{ test_score.score }} </h2>
</h3>
```

If test day is ２０１７/０３/０３,２０１７０３０３ is registed in test_date of User.And test score is registed in score(for example,if score is 60,60 is registed)
The kind of data of user・test_date・score is many in same user.For example,the data is

```
Tom ２０１７０８０９　６０
Tom ２０１７０８１０　１００
Tom ２０１７１０１０　３０
```

in that case test.html is

```
<h3>Your score is
      <h2 class="one">３０</h2>
</h3>
```

But now,test.html is

```
<h3>Your score is
      <h2 class="one">６０</h2>
</h3>
```

６０　is first registed data ,so current my system shows it .I think `test_score = User.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('test_date')[0]` get most newest (biggest) data Tom ２０１７０８１０　１００ because of Django document.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: What is deciding factor in case there is conflict ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models look fishy.

You need to change the ordering to '**-test_date**'

```
@login_required
def test(request):
   test_score = User.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-test_date')
   if test_score:
       test_score = test_score[0]
   else:
       return Http404
   return render(request, 'test.html', {'test_score': test_score})
```